# How to animate drawing shape fit in 60 second?

Tags: swift, animation, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I'm new to Swift and I don't have too much information about it.I would like to create animated clock with filling '**CAShapeLayer**' path in time interval than tried to make it with '**CABasicAnimation**' in 60 seconds. The shape fills in 49 sec and animation finish fit in 60 seconds, so it's not working as desired. Than I changed `animation.byValue = 0.1` but the result is same. Some one have an idea about this issue?

My code is :

```
    var startAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2
    var endAngle = CGFloat.pi * 2
    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        let center = view.center
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        animate(layer: shapeLayer) //Animation func

            view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    private func animate(layer: CAShapeLayer) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 1.0
        animation.duration = 60.0 //I think is counting by seconds?
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "strokeEndAnimation")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you made the BezierPath.

Try this instead:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeStart = 0
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    shapeLayer.position = self.view.center
    shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, -CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
```

The arcCenter must be at .zero and set the shape's center as the center of the view. Your circle will start animating from the right most point though, therefore add a CATransform to rotate the shape 90 degrees counterclockwise.